# Does 'Battery Protection Mode' turn on automatically?

Tags: charging, lenovo

I'm the founder of a company that deploys Android tablets into a hospital

Making sure our tablets are plugged in is really important to us. When devices get unplugged we alert hospital staff to plug them back in.

Devices are showing up unplugged when they’re plugged in, reducing staff confidence in us.

What we know..

- Patients occasionally unplug cords to charge their phones
- We had a bunch of low quality cords that were falling out. We replaced most of them yesterday
- We’ve observed devices not charging when plugged in: the charging light flicks on, then immediately off after being plugged in
- We have not changed any default battery settings
- The problems have been mostly limited to a couple of devices
- Our MDM solution (Esper) shows us battery level graphs that level off at 60%

.. we suspect that like ‘battery protection mode’ is being enabled automatically somehow

Some (potentially) useful context

- Devices: Lenovo M8s running Android 9
- Devices are in kiosk mode running our single (low battery use) app with screens

Comment: Using a tablet with plugged-in USB cord will destroy the USB charging port in no time because of the leverage effect of the USB plug. Therefore I would strongly recommend to use USB cables that work like Apple's magsafe - if the force is too high the magnetic connection breaks and the cable disconnects from the device.

Answer (score 5):

I got a response from our support contact at Esper. This is apparently a Lenovo feature.

> Lenovo "Battery Protection Mode" will be automatically enabled if the device is continually charging for around 7 days.
>
> This is a feature designed by Lenovo to reduce excessive battery heat and degradation.
>
> While plugged in the device will stay at a charge level of about 60%, and will slightly vary at times but should dip no lower than 50%.

Comment: Thanks for the initiative and self-answering! Apparently, yes, this is a Lenovo feature: [HowTo enable Battery Protection Mode - Smart Tab](https://support.lenovo.com/id/en/solutions/ht510061-howto-enable-battery-protection-mode-smart-tab). The "7-day automatically" is good to know since looks like it's not documented anywhere.